Do satellites in orbit create Relativity paradoxes?
Can someone point out the flaw in this very realistic scenario below?
I will start by stating established first principles of the applicable orbital and relativistic conditions.
Then I will describe my hypothetical scenario.
And finally, I will ask for an explanation of what is ACTUALLY happening (which is the main point of the post).
First Principles from Special and General Relativity
• Nothing can travel through Space or any other medium faster than c and this places a speed limit on the flow of information
• Clocks in a stronger gravitational field tick more slowly than those in a weaker gravitational field
• The arrow of time, the nature of Spacetime, and the limit of c prohibit access to the past within same frame of reference
• By travelling to and then returning from relatively stronger gravitational fields to one's original reference frame, one can 'access the future' in the original reference frame
Hypothetical Scenario of a Geosynchronous Satellite
Let us say Jack builds a brand new satellite so that we can point to a time when Jack and the satellite existed, in contact, in the same reference frame.
Let us say that Jack launches his satellite into geosynchronous orbit in 1st July 1954 (~70 years ago).
Let us agree, for simplicity's sake, that the geosynchronous orbit is high enough that the required orbital speed does not create any time dilation due to Special Relativistic effects. Also, let's make the simplistic assumption that transfer of information between the satellite and the launch site is instantaneous (in reality, this is a very small fraction of a fraction of a second, but I prefer to equate it to ~0 so as not to muddy the waters on my main questions below).
Let us agree, however, that the differential slope in gravitational fields between the geosynchronous orbit and Jack's launch site on Earth does create time dilation due to General Relativistic effects of approximately 45 microseconds per day; i.e., the clocks on the satellite tick faster to the tune of 45/1,000,000 seconds per day every day.
Let us finally agree that the satellite remains in perfect, stable, circular orbit in perpetuity.
Now, if Jack were to return to the launch site today in 2024 (so, ~70 years later), he would look up to a satellite which now exists approximately 1.15 seconds in his future (45/1,000,000 seconds per day × 365.25 days per year ×70 reference frame years in orbit).
Questions

Given the near instantaneous flow of information between the satellite and Jack, could the satellite claim that, by observing its launch site on Earth in real time, it is looking 1.15 seconds into its own past?

Let us say the satellite guns its thrusters to return to the same spot of launch where Jack happens to be waiting, what has happened here (see i through iii below):


i) did Jack travel into his own future to 'catch-up' to the satellite? Unlikely since Jack's gravitational field has stayed constant over the 70 years and we are ignoring any time dilation due to speed differentials. OR
ii) did the satellite travel back to 'its past' to 'catch-down' to Jack? This would violate causality and create meaningless physical constructs, so, I think not.
iii) has the satellite, over the course of its spatial return to origin, decelerated its procession through time such that it somehow allows Jack to catch-up by the time they are re-united?

let's make the simplistic assumption that transfer of information between the satellite and the launch site is instantaneous  You cannot pick which bits of relativity you want to use.  It's all or nothing.  Picking some things and leaving out others creates paradoxes because the theory is only self-consistent if you include all of it.

Actually, Stephen, if you would have checked, you would know that any time dilation due to Special Relativity does not is only a very small fraction of that due to General Relativity. If you're going to be snarky, can you at least be sure of what you're talking about? @StephenG-HelpUkraine

Very little of this question makes sense. “Access the past” and “access the future” are weird terms that I have never seen before. They are not part of SR so they should either be avoided or defined. Similarly with “exists 1.15 s in his future”. This is not a standard concept so it should either be avoided or defined clearly

@Dale, the helpful poster (Paulina) has been able to mostly understand and respond to my question as originally stated. Perhaps the limit of understanding is occurring on your end. ‍♂️

Perhaps. But certainly the terminology is non-standard and should be avoided or defined. The things you list as first principles from SR and GR are not first principles, and some of them may not even be from SR or GR

Okay, Dale, I'll bite: can you tell me what needs to be "defined" that you think hasn't been? Let's put some of your eagerness to good use.

I already told you specifically above

There is only one geosynchronous orbit, and in it, both SR and GR effects are about equally strong. You cannot just magically have a far enough away geosynchronous orbit that SR can be ignored in favour of GR.

The satellite is not looking into its own past. It's looking at Jack's present, the clocks in which happen to read a time 1.15 seconds earlier than the clocks on the satellite. As to your second question, it's the third option. As the satellite descends, thr clock slows down due to the increasing gravitational field strength to exactly match the speed of Jack's clock. They will read different times though, which would be experimental evidence for gravitational time dilation.

Paulina, many thanks for your answer. I thought it might be iii), but I was having trouble understanding it intuitively.
